# Issues with Qt VS plugin

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt4

For some reason that I can't track down, one of our solutions that contains projects based on the Qt plugin is breaking down.

We have multiple developers working on the same projects.  The Qt Options has a versions setting and we all are using the same name but the path is different on our different machines.  This seems to work OK much of the time because the property sheet that the plugin sets up seems to perform some magic on the QT4VSPropertySheet.props file so that QTDIR is reset for the local machine.

Unfortunately, for reasons I can't figure out, it sometimes doesn't do this.  Another member of the team just added several projects that where separate into a solution.  Some of them have the QTDIR setting changed in the property sheet to my local machine, others do not.

Version of VS is 2010, version of the plugin is 1.1.7.  I do have QTDIR set as an environment variable on my local machine.  Doesn't seem to solve the problem.

So far it's just the one solution.  It first showed up as a problem with the release build of one project in the solution on the build server.  We logged into the build server and built the project by hand once and fixed the issue.  Now there's a crap load of projects that only build on some machines.

Any ideas WTF is going on here?

---

More info: problem projects seem to have forgotten that they are Qt plugin projects.  Trying to make them such by saying "Convert to Qt Project" causes severe absurdity.  QTDIR ends up being set to weird crap like "path_to_project\$(QTDIR)"

---

Missing bits:

```
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <UserProperties QtVersion_x0020_Win32="Qt4" />
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
```

With that stuff missing the project won't work right.  Don't know what removed it.  Trying to use the menu to do it resulted in serious hosing.  Editing with notepad and putting those bits back in, right before the `</Project>` tag, fixed the problem.

Comment: Found my problem - was unrelated to the property sheets.  Something had altered the project file so that the magic bits that told it to be controlled by the plugin where missing.  Putting those bits back solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Hit this problem with the Qt prop sheets, one solution is to make sure the property sheets aren't included in source control and have each machine rebuild them locally.  In the end we ended up having to redo the installs so that Qt was on the same path on every developers machine.